# Binding value to <Style> tag Angular 2 template

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have a component that using template from html file , the template like this

```html
<div class="abc"></div>
<style>
    .abc {
        background-color: {{myColor}}
    }
</style>
```

Is there anyway to dynamic binding the value of background-color ? 
Actually i can do that by moving css to inline html like this `<div class="abc" [style.background-color]="myColor"></div>` , but for some reason i cant do that.

Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks you very much!

Comment: That's not supported by Angular2. You can do something like this with CSS variables on browsers that support it. I guess Angular2 will eventually add shimming of CSS variables for browsers that don't support it natively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [ng2 styler](https://github.com/cstefanache/ng2-styler) or write your own decorator that interpolates css imported as text based on the ng2 styler code

in four decorator function you could use :

`metaInformation = window['Reflect'].getOwnMetadata('annotations', target)`

And then:

```
for (let metadata of metainformation){ 
   if (metadata instanceof ComponentMetadata){
     //interpolate somecsstext and add it to to metadata.styles
     //as if it was added from the styles property 
     //of the component decorator metadata
     metadata.styles = [...metadata.styles, somecsstext
        .replace(/{{([a-z1-9]+)}}/ig, function (match, prop) {
          return yourVaribles[prop];
        })];


   }
}
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that the intention to ass a style tag in your component seems weird and violate parts of the web-component philosophy. You probably want want to to do that in style metadata so that you can get css encapsulation etc